# Checking each value of a console output

Tags: c#

I would like to read each value one by one, every single one they keep typing until they press a value which ends the "input checking".

I have checked several other posts but none works for me, because I don't want to use **arrays or lists**, the value must be checked once, and if that happens then work with that.

I have managed to achieve this:

```
    char END = '#', value;
    bool found= false;
    int count = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Write a line ending in '#'.");
    value = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
    if (value == END) 
        found = true;

    while (!found) 
    {
        count++;
        value = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
        if (value == END) 
            found = true;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("You have typed " + count);
```

Comment: Waht do you mean by "value of a console input"? Do you want read *string by string* or *char by char*?

Comment: I changed to output. Thanks @DmitryBychenko. I want to read char by char, or in another case, int by int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use StringBuilder object, you can add characters one by one to it. I have also simplified your logic a lot.

```
    char END = '#';
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
    Console.WriteLine("Write a line ending in '#'.");

    while (true) 
    {
        var ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
        if (ch == END) 
            break;
        sb.Append(ch)
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("You have typed " + sb.ToString());
```

Comment: The goal is to help each other learn.  OP seems new to this so introducing StringBuilder and giving no explanation for any of your changes isnt really helpful.  Its not about points...

Comment: Thank you @pm100. I'm sure this is definetely the best solution for it, and much improved. But now, is there a more rudimental way, similar to mine..? Probably I'm missing something which is pretty much low level coding.. Basically, I don't know if it is appropiate to go to class with something we have never used which clearly it's not my creation.. I hope you understand what I mean..

Comment: @Raül you can just build a string the slower and less efficient way by concatenating the string (`someString += ch;`).  That should be something basic enough for your class, and its really the only other way to do this if you want to display the final `string`.  If you just want the count of characters thats a different story

Comment: Hello @maccettura, i don't want to show any string. I just want to count how many char have there been before the 'END' mark.

Comment: if you just want to count then you original code is OK, except change to use my loop stlye to only have one read statment

Answer (score -1):

Something like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Console.WriteLine("Write a line ending in '#'.");
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    do
    {
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

        // Evaluate Input Key
        if (int.TryParse(keyInfo.Key.ToString(), out int i))
        {
            ; // do something with an int
        }
        else
        {
            ; // do something with char 
        }

        if (keyInfo.KeyChar != '#') 
        {
            sb.Append(keyInfo.KeyChar);
        }
    }
    while (keyInfo.KeyChar != '#');

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"You typed '{sb.ToString()}' which is {sb.Length.ToString()} character(s).");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```